# How can I rotate a page with PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm editing a PDF file with pyPDF2. I managed to generate the PDF I want but I've yet to rotate some pages.

I went to [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html) and found two methods: `rotateClockwise` and `rotateCounterClockwise`, and while they say the parameter is an **int**, I can't make it work. Python says:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IndirectObject' and 'int'
```

To produce this error:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter


reader = PdfFileReader("example.pdf")

with open("out.pdf", "wb") as fh:
    writer = PdfFileWriter(fh)
    page = reader.getPage(0)
    page.rotateCounterClockwise(90)
    writer.addPage(page)
```

I can't find someone explaining the procedure. There is, however, a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646375/pypdf-indirectobject-in-rotate) in stackoverflow but the answer's just vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This was a known bug](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/337) with the `rotateClockwise` function. [This was fixed](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/pull/338/commits/c3231c7ded644f9afe891a9a1e58aa09b60bbf97).

For older versions of PyPDF2: Just edit the '_rotate' method in your `pdf.py` with this fix

```
def _rotate(self, angle):
    rotateObj = self.get("/Rotate", 0)
    currentAngle = rotateObj if isinstance(rotateObj, int) else rotateObj.getObject()
    self[NameObject("/Rotate")] = NumberObject(currentAngle + angle)
```

Comment: It looks like now it is fixed.

Comment: I think the fix wasn't released to PyPI for a while. Now it is :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your three lines with this:

`output.addPage(input1.getPage(i).rotateCounterClockwise(90))`

I think the rotate has to be done to a getPage call and not on the "extracted" page.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reaching this question later, in more recent version of `PyPDF2`, `rotateClockwise` and `rotateCounterClockwise` is deprecated and replaced with `rotate` which can directly be applied to a page.

```py
>>> new_page = page.rotate(90) # Clockwise
>>> new_page = page.rotate(-90) # CounterClockwise
```