# Rotating a single-paged PDF file with Python pyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm working on a project, where one functionality will be for the user to determine the path of a PDF document and whether it is supposed to be rotated or not. For some reason when I check the rotate checkbox, the PDF file becomes empty. Adobe Reader cannot open it, saying it "has no pages". So apparently in the process of rotating a page it has been deleted?

I don't want to create a new PDF file. I prefer overwriting the original one.

Here is my code:

```
import PyPDF2

window = Tk()
window.title("PDF ROT")
window.geometry('500x500')

rot = IntVar()
Rotate = Checkbutton(window, text="Does it need to be rotated?", variable = rot)
Rotate.grid (column = 0, row = 4)




sciezka = Entry(window, width = 30)
sciezka.grid (column = 0, row = 3)


def funkcja ():
    path = sciezka.get()

    if (rot.get() == 1):

        pdf_in = open(path, 'rb')
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_in)
        pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
        page.rotateClockwise(90)

        pdf_out = open(path, 'wb')
        pdf_writer.write(pdf_out)
        pdf_out.close()
        pdf_in.close()


AccButton = Button(window, text = "Accept data", command = funkcja)
AccButton.grid(column=7, row = 0)
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and remove the `tkinter` part, it's irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rotate a page in pyPDF2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615771/how-can-i-rotate-a-page-in-pypdf2)